# What dungeon-based game has a mirror that creates a replica of your character?

Tags: game-identification

I had played a game once as a child and yesterday I encountered a picture of it (given below) so I want to know which game it is.

[image: image I found]

It was on one of those 'Only 90's kids will remember' posts on Facebook.

When I had played I guess I used to play using arrow keys to move and the <kbd>shift</kbd> key to attack, but I don't remember exactly. There was one level in which you go into mirror and then it creates a replica of your character and it runs and we have to chase through levels and there were spikes too which used to cause instant death.

That's all I remember. Can someone tell which game it is?

Comment: Didn't downvote, but it might be because it's a pretty iconic game, and a reverse image search in Google gives you the answer instantly, showing little research effort.

Comment: @Kareen It would have been much more modest to ask if OP knows about reverse image search technology. Not everyone is as amazing as you when it comes to using technology.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus OP asked why they were being downvoted, so I pointed out a possible reason. They deleted the comment, so I will assume they agreed with that answer, or at least accepted it. I did not simply stroll in and criticize the question out of the blue.

Comment: @Kareen Yes that's true but I really don't know how to reverse search

Comment: @ShubhamWagh I meant no offense, though I'm sorry if I caused you any. As for reverse image search, if you're using Chrome, you can right-click on an image and "Search Google for this image". Otherwise, you can go to Google's image search and click on the camera icon to search by image.

Comment: @Kareen Oh ok thanks! Nope I wasn't offended a single time.

Comment: http://playdosgamesonline.com/prince-of-persia.html

Comment: Also might be of interest: http://www.avclub.com/article/fairies-dancing-screen-4-classic-video-game-sprite-215639 (it's number 4).

Comment: Just used image search to see how well it worked and it is awesome.  Thanks for suggesting it!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

That's the original [Prince of Persia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_of_Persia) game.  Fun fact: It actually came out for computers pre-PC days, on the Apple IIe.

Comment: Actually, it was a very dense, unforgiving, and hard to follow game. It wasn't very good at telling you when you did something right, and straight up killed you when you did something wrong. As games went, there's a lot it could've done better.

Comment: It sent you back to the start of the level when you did something wrong ("death").  It let you proceed when you did something right.  It started off with simple problems, taught you to master them, then gave you complex problems where it was presumed you had mastered the simple ones.  The 60 minute limit was the hard part in a sense; finishing it on your first attempt was hard, but once you mastered the techniques the early game flies by; an interative mastery, where the successful plot feels like an action hero compared to your first play's bumbling idiot.

Comment: Bah kids these days. Bring back the days of 3 lives and no continues and still having to beat 100 levels. That's a game.

Comment: In 1977, "PC" / "Personal Computer" largely meant the Apple ][.  The use solely for IBM-compatible PCs wasn't until much later.  And Prince of Persia didn't come out pre-PC days; it came out in 1989, almost a decade into the PC era.  It was, however, developed for the Apple ][ (though quickly ported to the PC within a year).

Comment: @coteyr that's what UUDDLRLRBABAS is for :D

Comment: @theonlygusti Welcome to popular question types.  *shrug*  For what it's worth, I thoroughly despise these questions.  But the community absolutely adores them.

Comment: @theonlygusti: it’s almost as if the automated system for awarding made-up internet points on some website doesn’t rigorously assess effort!

Answer (score 14):

That appears to be [Prince of Persia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_of_Persia_(1989_video_game)).  See link to more details.